# Get (calculate) total width of mutiple elements with dynamic widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm going to be as pedagogic as possible!

So I have a list of li's wrapped within a ul.

```
<ul class="ulclass">
   <li class="liclass">
       <div class="button">expand</div>
       <img src="600px_wide.jpg"/>
   </li>
   <li class="liclass">
       <div class="button">expand</div>
       <img src="800px_wide.jpg"/>
   </li>
   <li class="liclass">
       <div class="button">expand</div>
       <img src="300px_wide.jpg"/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

within each **li** element there is a button, when clicked the **li** will expand to the width of the nested image. So if the image is 800px wide the **li** will expand accordingly.

Now the situation is that I want to calculate the total width of all the li's dynamically. 
Right now I'm using something like:

```
$(li).each(function() {
totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width());
});
```

which will get the width of all the li's on page load. But after expanding say one li the width value doesn't change. **I want the total width to change when I expand/contract the li's** A event listener maybe? I'm really new when it comes to callbacks and such. So I would like some guidance at least. Maybe it's not even possible...

I Appreciate all help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

James' answer is good, but Depending on how often/how many places the value is read, you might prefer to call that code whenever the value is asked for. So instead of `someDependentFunction(totalWidth)`, you would have `someDependentFunction(totalWidth())`, where `totalWidth` is:

```
function totalWidth = new function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(li).each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).width());
    });
    return total;
}
```

As James said, if you're worried about the performance of calling $(li), then if it's anything like the YUI equivalent it will cache the results after the first call so it really shouldn't be much at all. I'm not really a jQuery pro though, so that might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call this code which calculates the width each time that you expand or contract an `li`.  Unless you have a huge number of `li` elements, the performance of just adding them all back up again shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I'll have about 10-20 li's not sure if it's considered a lot for performance. Also I want to keep the code so clean as possible.